# Two settings field in one form

Tags: settings-api

is it possible to have two settings fields in one form?

```
<?php
    echo '<form method="post" action="options.php">';
    settings_fields( 'my-plugin-settings-group-1' );
    settings_fields( 'my-plugin-settings-group-2' );
?>
```

I tried it but it doesn't work, only one settings_fields is saved.

any ideas or other solutions?

Comment: @ialocin I'm already aware of that, but my settings have a kind of complicated structure, so I prefer to avoid this.

Comment: Avoid what? The settings API?